# Can open-tube manometers be used to measure atmospheric pressure?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

I was going through a slide made by my physics professor and was wondering about the statement made at the bottom: "This cannot be used to measure the atmospheric pressure". 
Why is that so?

**Given the derived equation: if we knew the pressure of a different inert gas (enclosed in the chamber), the density of the liquid and the height, could we not solve for the atmospheric pressure (on the exposed end of the device)?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The open tube manometer measures the pressure **difference** between the gas in the container and the air outside. If you have atmospheric pressure on both sides of the liquid, the height in the two sides is equal ($y_2=y_1$). You get that the pressure difference is $0$, but not what the pressure is.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. I meant if the gas inside the closed chamber was some OTHER inert gas of known pressure and the right side of the manometer was exposed to the outside atmosphere, then there would be a corresponding change in height, no? Would you then be able to calculate the atmospheric pressure?

Comment: In principle yes, but how would you know the pressure of that gas?

Comment: That was exactly what I was unsure about. I suppose it is probably impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the set up. Any device you draw that presents an inertial system except for one force input, will only change under the influence of that one input. Its not just that you can in fact measure atmospheric pressure with it, but that is actually the only thing you can measure with it. Whether the device would be able to be used for measuring atmospheric pressure when build, is another matter, but what's on your drawing can.

The thing that gives your professor reason to write that, is the fact that the pressure of the inert gas is what this device is supposed to measure, meaning it may vary, which doesn't really show very well in either the drawing or the formulas